# Jquery late binding using on - Old form not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, syntax, jquery-selectors

I can't figure out why option (1) doesn't work.
I have read the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) but missed/couldn't find an answer.

Can someone please explain this or point me to the documentation regarding this?

```
1. $('#MAIN a[href="#PAGE"]').on( 'click',function(event){ alert("1"); });
2. $(document).on('click', '#MAIN a[href="#PAGE"]', function(event){ alert("2"); });
```

thanks.

Comment: Show us your html please? `.on` - Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. So there much be something wrong in the DOM or binding, HTML will help, cheers , **And** please don't get confuse between live and .on, live is deprecated and use .on instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first form hooks up regular events on the links, while the second form hooks up a delegate event on the document level.

The first one is the same as:

```
$('#MAIN a[href="#PAGE"]').click(function(event){ alert("1"); });
```

The first form needs the links to be present when you run the code. The events won't be there for links that you add later on.

The second form catches the event when it bubbles up to the document level, so it also works for links that you add later on.

Preferably you should hook up the delegate event as close to the target elements as possible. If the `#MAIN` element is present when you hook it up, you would use that instead of the document:

```
$('#MAIN').on('click', 'a[href="#PAGE"]', function(event){ alert("2"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell if this is the issue without some HTML & script execution info, but the first one searches for elements (well, a single element in this case) that matches the selector, and attaches an event handler to it.

The second case attaches the event handler to document.  Whenever a click event happens, it tests to see if the event target matches the selector, and fires the event if so.  This is why you can set the event up in advance and create the elements dynamically... it does have a performance hit to do so, however.